# Как проложить интернет?

Tags: сеть, wan

Есть небольшой населенный пункт. Нужно предоставить этому пункту доступ к интернету (через сетку). Что для этого нужно? от А до Я. (В подробностях)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариант 1. ВОЛС (Волоконно-оптическая линия связи).

1. Предварительно подумать а так ли оно надо?
2. Лицензирование деятельности как оператора связи
3. Согласование прокладки (земля/воздух) с нужными инстанциями
4. Закупка кабеля.
5. Поиск подрядчика.
6. Выбор оператора/договор о предоставление порта доступа с оператором.

Вариант 2. РРЛС (Радиорелейная линия связи).

1. Предварительно подумать а так ли оно надо?
2. Лицензирование деятельности как оператора связи
3. Согласование/Лицензирование радиочастот.
4. Согласование на размещение оборудования (высотные дома, вышки связи).
5. При необходимости, строительство вышек связи с арендой участка земли.
6. Закупка необходимого оборудования.
7. Выбор оператора/договор о предоставление порта доступа с оператором.

В целом все выливается в крупные суммы (не в один миллион!). Укажите следующее, и можно будет судить о масштабах и суммах:

1. Удаленность нас.пункта от ближайших линий связи или города. (Лучше укажите на Я.Картах)
2. Рельеф местности.
3. Количество предполагаемых абонентов.

Бизнес-план можно найти в гугле.

Comment: 1 http://maps.yandex.ua/-/CVa8r8Ng2 Там равнина, только некоторая часть (справа сверху) ниже общего уровняРадиус покрытия всего 2 километра. Нет мощной вайфай точки которая могла качественно покрыть 2-4 км?3 300-2000 чел

Comment: Да, как вариант, как каналообразующее оборудование использовать Ubiquiti RocketM5+RocketDish (5Hz), а там уже раздавать RocketM Ti + airMAX Titanium Sectors (2.4Hz, 5Hz), у клиентов использовать NanoStationM2/M5. На практике я получал из RocketM5 + RocketDish на расстоянии 14.5 км ~130Мб/с. Для большей пропускной способности советую airFiber, но его надо заказывать, в Подмосковье мы ждали 1.5 месяца.

Answer (score 1):

Есть точки Ubiquiti, в принципе, их можно попробовать. [ubnt.com](http://ubnt.com)Вообще, вопрос в бюджете. Можно сделать качественную сеть на 2.4 Ггц, с базовой станцией или без.

Comment: Соглашусь с Валерием, одно но.., использование 5Ггц требует лицензирования, 2.4 с оговоркой по мощности вроде как не требует. При использовании диапазона 2.4 (оборудование RocketM - Nanostation NSM2 получали в режиме точка - многоточка в районе 30-50 Мбит на клиента, при удалении до 3 км.) И это в городе, где 2.4 эфир грязный.